# How to delete infrastructure resources if we loose tfstate file in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created a terraform template to deploy EC2 VM. It also creates subnet, security groups, network interfaces required to create EC2 VM.
I uploaded this terraform template to the S3 bucket. Next, I created the Lambda function that downloads this terraform template and creates resources.
I don't have the `tfstate` file as the Lambda function is terminated. Now, I want to destroy these resources created by the Lambda function using Terraform template.

How can I do that?

I have tried the following things but didn't work:

1. I have a `terraform plan` file in the local environment. Didn't find a way to pass this to `terraform destroy`.
2. When I tried this template from my local environment, it generated a `tfstate` file. I used that file to destroy resources but got the following error:
   Terraform detected the following changes made outside of terraform since the last `terraform apply`.
3. I tried `terraform refresh` and `terraform delete` to refresh the state of resources and destroy them.
4. I tried `terraform plan -destroy` and `terraform apply -destroy` commands as well.

Is there any other way to delete these resources other than manually?

Comment: 1. You would pass this to `terraform apply`. 2. Could we see that output? 3. Unsure since there is no `terraform delete` subcommand. 4. `terraform plan -destroy` would have worked with the state and config. Could you elaborate further than just that you tried it?

Comment: If you lost TF state file, you have to go to AWS console and clean up everything manually.

Comment: @Marcin I cleaned up things manually. I am looking for a way to delete through some commands. My template created 16 resources. Going through each service then locating resources is a bit difficult task.

Comment: No command will help if you don't know which resources you've created. The only universal solution is `aws-nuke` to delete everything.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I passed the same plan file to apply but it didn't work because some of the resources were already there with the same name. Which command output you would like to see? What extra details you need?

Comment: @Marcin I checked the CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda Function that I created. From logs, I gathered all the Resource IDs and deleted them manually.

The other solution which I added in my Lambda is whenever it creates resources, upload the tfstate file to the S3 bucket for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

- Use https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer to import back resources with state file saved locally
- run Terraform plan to make sure imported resources are match what's out there
- Use https://github.com/cloudskiff/driftctl to compare for coverage of the imported resources
- Run Terraform destroy again

Since you have the terraform resources and templates you cloud also import resources manually into state file using terraform import, but test the upper workflow first.